# Debug for an if statement in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a piece of code to make sure the user enters a "scrap amount" if they have entered a "scrap code". When I apply and use the code for Scrap1, everything works great. When I try to apply that same code with the next set of variable names, I get an error that says my code "has an ambiguous name detected. I have checked my variable names and the code until my eyes bled. Everything looks fine to me. Does anyone see an error that I have missed?

```
'check to see that there is a scrap amount if a code has been entered #1.

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     If Me.ScrapCodes1.Value Then
     If Me.ScrapAmount1 = 0 Then
          Cancel = True
          MsgBox "If Scrap Code is selected, then Scrap Amount must have a value."
     End If
     End If
End Sub


'check to see that there is a scrap amount if a code has been entered #2.
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     If Me.ScrapCodes2.Value Then
     If Me.ScrapAmount2 = 0 Then
          Cancel = True
          MsgBox "If Scrap Code is selected, then Scrap Amount must have a value."
     End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you created TWO `Form_BeforeUpdate` events? You just need to include all code in the ONE event

Comment: Thank you Dbmitch! That fixed it!  I should have known that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assemble in one sub:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    ' check to see that there is a scrap amount if a code has been entered #1.
    If Me.ScrapCodes1.Value Then
        If Me.ScrapAmount1 = 0 Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    ' check to see that there is a scrap amount if a code has been entered #2.
    If Me.ScrapCodes2.Value Then
        If Me.ScrapAmount2 = 0 Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    If Cancel = True Then
        MsgBox "If Scrap Code is selected, then Scrap Amount must have a value."
    end If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I put all of them into the same before_update and it worked.